# ST_SummaryStats gives unknown values (infinity and different values) when clipping raster with buffer

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geotiff-tiff, postgis-raster

I am loading a raster to postgis (see postgis version and command below)

```
raster2pgsql /path_to_raster/temp-221025_12.tif -d icon_test -F -n name | PGPASSWORD=<PASS> psql -d <myDB> -h <host> -U <user> -p <port>
```

> POSTGIS="3.1.2 cbe925d" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="120"
> GEOS="3.7.1-CAPI-1.11.1 27a5e771" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016"
> GDAL="GDAL 2.1.2, released 2016/10/24" LIBXML="2.9.4" LIBJSON="0.12.1"
> LIBPROTOBUF="1.2.1" WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)" RASTER

I am trying to get stats of pixels near a point with this query:

```
SELECT name,ST_SummaryStats(
ST_Clip(rast, ST_buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-90.37083 15.47083)',4326), 3000*0.00001)) 
) from icon_test
```

But it gives me BAD stats according to my knowledge (check columns in the image)
[image]

I have loaded the tif to QGIS and overlaying the point buffer and it overlays to 4 pixels as the stats says but I was expecting mean as ((18.797+18.391+17.976+17.544)/4) = 18.177 and max=18.797 and min=17.544 (based on the image)
[image]

Why ST_SummaryStats is not giving the expected stats ?

[Link to raster if you want to download](https://cloud1.on.gt/data/icon/temp-221025_12.tif)

UPDATE 1 using envelope works for this coord:

```
SELECT name,
(ST_SummaryStats(
        ST_Clip(rast, st_envelope(ST_buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-90.37083 15.47083)',4326), 3000*0.00001))
        ) 
    )
).* from icon_test
```

Result:

```
name              |count|sum              |mean             |stddev            |min               |max               |
------------------+-----+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
temp-221025_12.tif|    4|72.70815658569336|18.17703914642334|0.4666503646805367|17.544031143188477|18.797155380249023|
```

Result for coord. POINT(-90.6 14.52):

```
name              |count|sum      |mean     |stddev  |min                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |max               |
------------------+-----+---------+---------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
temp-221025_12.tif|    4|-Infinity|-Infinity|Infinity|-17976931348623157000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000|13.930984497070312|
```

UPDATE 2 Raster STATS same with POSTGIS and cli-GDAL:

```
count |sum             |mean              |stddev            |min               |max               |
------+----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
990525|23331638.4433757|23.554820366346835|5.6419397045642325|-4.649328708648682|31.385828018188477|
```

UPDATE 3 pixel values of clip:

```
select 
 ST_PixelAsPoints(
    ST_CLIP(rast, ST_buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT (-90.37083 15.47083)',4326), 3000*0.00001))
    ) geom
from icon_test

geom                                                                             |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
(0101000020E610000033333333339B56C0CCCCCCCCCC0C2F40,-1.7976931348623157e+308,1,1)|
(0101000020E610000000000000009856C0CCCCCCCCCC0C2F40,-1.7976931348623157e+308,2,1)|
(0101000020E610000033333333339B56C03233333333F32E40,-1.7976931348623157e+308,1,2)|
(0101000020E610000000000000009856C03233333333F32E40,17.544031143188477,2,2)      |
```

UPDATE 4:
I am unable to get this to work for all rasters, any other ideas?

Comment: Like I said, the nodata value needs to be set, ohterwise you're doing stat on -infinity values. Can you try the edit I did on my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think the way `ST_Clip` works is that it keep the data if and only if the center of the pixel is in your geom.

So seeing your image only the bottom right pixel will be kept. But the resulting raster would still include 4 pixels because the geom intersects with 4 pixels. Others pixels will be with the value 'nodata', which by default will be `ST_MinPossibleValue(ST_BandPixelType(rast, band))`, in your case probably -infinity.

One way to handle that would probably be to add half of the pixel size to the buffer (if you have square pixels, otherwise it will be more complicated), but you need to handle the corners too. So I think you need to switch to square selection after having your circle:

```
SELECT 
  name,
  ST_SummaryStats(
    ST_Clip(
      rast, 
      ST_Enveloppe(
        ST_buffer(
          ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-90.37083 15.47083)', 4326),
          3000*0.00001 + ST_PixelWidth(rast)/2
        )
      )
    ) 
  ) 
from icon_test
```

It's just an idea, maybe there is specific cases that I missed.

And after that, you still need to handle missing values in your resulting raster. Maybe there is a problem with the `nodata_value` of the resulting raster, because it should be ignored by `ST_SummaryStats` but it doesn't seems like it is. Maybe try to set a `nodataval` in `ST_Clip` ?

**EDIT:**

Like I said, I think you second problem is the nodata value, you need to set it for it to work as intended. I think this should work:

```
SELECT 
  name,
  ST_SummaryStats(
    ST_SetBandNoDataValue(
      ST_Clip(
        rast, 
        ST_Enveloppe(
          ST_buffer(
            ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-90.37083 15.47083)', 4326),
            3000*0.00001 + ST_PixelWidth(rast)/2
          )
        ),
        FLOAT8 '-infinity'
      ),
      FLOAT8 '-infinity'
    ),
    TRUE
  ) 
from icon_test
```

Comment: tested with envelope and works for the testing point but not for other points, see UPDATE 1 of my question. Stats of raster as geotiff with GDAL and with Postgis shows same values. seems no missing or novalues points.

Comment: Instead of `ST_SummaryStats`, can you display the values of the raster returned by `ST_Clip` to see what's going on ?

Comment: is what I attempted to do and got this...  and seems that is the data take for summary but pixels has data if I enlarge buffer got more valid values but always the -1.79e+318 values... see UPDATE 3

Comment: You can surround ST_PixelAsPoints() with ().* for better display: (ST_PixelAsPoints()).*

Comment: `-1.7976931348623157e+308` is minus infinity, so the result of `ST_SummaryStats` is logical. Like I said, you get the pixel but filled with nodata, but because nodata is not set in your original raster you get -infinty. You need to make `ST_SummaryStats` understand that the -infinity is nodata. Try using `ST_SetBandNoDataValue` to set nodata to -infinity. You can also use your own nodata (like -10000 for example) and set it in both `ST_SetBandNoDataValue` and `ST_Clip`.